# Does preventing consecutive characters in a password actually increase security?

Tags: passwords

Sometimes I try to use a password that I can easily remember but is hard for a computer to guess. It, for example (this is not my method), might consist of 2 words, followed by a number of repeated special characters, followed by a word. This password is called "weak" by Apple and it won't let me use it 'because of consecutive characters'. It's 20 characters long and hard to guess, what makes it weak?

Comment: Note that the analysis script for the passwords is very simplistic. The goal is to prevent passwords with too few different characters: `1111aaaa!!!!`, for instance.

Comment: My guess is that is likely a reasonably (or even very) strong password that happens to tickle Apple's heuristics wrong.  Heuristics for password strength are a bit of a black art - I like zxcvbn's approach - large dictionary and pattern awareness combined with knowledge of common passwords and entropy calculations, but even that approach can get tripped up sometimes. Password strength is hard to do well.

Comment: @crovers, password strength is *impossible* to do well.  Passwords don't have strength, it's password-generation methods that have strength.  Strength meters attempt to guess at the method used to generate a given password, then display the strength of that method.

Comment: One thing is certain: *preventing consecutive characters increases annoyance.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preventing consecutive characters reduces security.  It's an attempt to prevent simple-to-guess passwords such as `00000000`, and to prevent people from padding weak passwords up to meet minimum lengths, eg. `helloooo`.  However, it also prevents the use of a wide range of strong passwords.

Sticking to just eight-character lowercase passwords for simplicity of analysis, there are 208,827,064,576 possible passwords.  Approximately 56,000,000,000 of those passwords contain consecutive identical characters, so in an attempt to prevent the use of weak passwords, you've reduced the complexity of a brute-force attack by about a quarter.

Comment: It's important to distinguish between "reduces security" and "reduces possible password choices" because those aren't always the same.  We have multiple security goals with password policies, and that requires balancing the prevention of weak passwords with the preservation of a sufficiently large pool of password choices.  I'm not saying that preventing two duplicate characters in a row is a good policy to enact (& N West didn't specify whether it started with two), but just because a policy eliminates a significant portion of possible passwords doesn't mean it automatically reduces security.

Comment: @PwdRsch, in this case, it eliminates a large number of "good" passwords, but only a small number of "bad" ones.

Comment: IF selected passwords were uniformly distributed (random) OR crackers only used brute force techniques, THEN I would _almost_ agree that "Preventing consecutive characters reduces security."  With few exceptions, passwords are not random and crackers are not stupid. Crackers use dictionaries and look for patterns like repeating characters (e.g., padding with Xs or periods or numeric sequences or keyboard patterns) along with selective brute forcing.  Also, the example you have chosen is extreme (although I'm sure it happens): 2 consecutive letters.

Comment: Typo? 56 -->50  50,135,658,326 = 26^8 - 26*25^7 -- still "about a quarter" (26.9 --> 24.0%).  Note as well, with 52 character set, 12.7%; 62 char set, 10.8%.  (I've simplified by not adjusting for passwords less than the max length.)  Increasing the password length has the opposite effect, increasing the % removed.

Comment: So can I expect a cracker to be able to crack with a dictionary, for example, a password like &&&&&2Timothy215###@@@ ? Does multiple 'sets' help complexity?

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

### No

The "no" is obvious. Anything that limits the kinds of passwords you can create makes the search space smaller. Others have shown the math on that.

### Yes

The "yes" part is more subtle, and I'm not sure it is even true any more as I haven't seen any recent research on this.

Passwords that comply with "complexity rules" are not inherently more secure than passwords which don't. And indeed there is a very real sense in which complexity rules weaken passwords. But when we ask people to conform to complexity rules they have tended to generate better passwords.

So the value of these requirements is about psychology and human behavior. If you state certain "complexity rules", you may be more likely to elicit better password creation.

#### A simple case

As fully noted anything that reduces the set of passwords that people can create will make the system weaker. But now consider the following two policies

Policy 1: Passwords can be any sequence from 8 to 24 characters in length consisting of the printable US-ASCII character.

Policy 2: Same as policy 1 *except* that passwords may not be from among a list of the 10,000 most common passwords.

Note that policy 2 defines a proper subset of set defined by policy 1, and therefore is weaker in a certain sense. But I hope that most people will agree that policy 2 is far more likely to produce stronger passwords than policy 1.

### Resolving the paradox

It might seem paradoxical that restricted the set of passwords that may be used would tend to increase the security of the created password, but the key to resolving the paradox is to recognize that the it is not only the number of passwords that can be generated by a system that matter, but the distribution of them.

If any "legal" password were as likely to be chosen as any other then restricting the set would be harmful. But we know that some passwords are far more commonly chosen then others. The distribution of human chosen passwords is very far from uniform. (Superficially, it might appear to follow a power law distribution, but it doesn't on [closer analysis](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3722).

But human chosen passwords follow a very "fat headed" distribution even if it isn't a power law distribution. If we find that imposing some restrictions flatten the distribution (make it closer to uniform), then the gain of doing that will often out-weigh the small reduction of the set of allowable passwords.

### But there are other problems with the rules

I believe that when some of these rules were first introduced, they succeeded at their goal. They substantially flattened the distribution of human created passwords. I am less sure that they succeed with this today, and so would like to see research on this. As these place a substantial burden on users, it isn't something we should be inflicting on them unless the benefits are big enough and clear enough to make it worthwhile.

These rules have led lots of people to grossly misunderstand what makes a password strong or weak. See ["I Added '!' at the End to Make It Secure"](https://www.usenix.org/conference/soups2015/proceedings/presentation/ur). We know that adding an "!" doesn't make a password more secure, but for many years people have been told that that is the kind of thing they need to do to pick a secure passwords. So we can't blame anyone for coming to that conclusion.

I also suspect that a number of IT managers do not understand the reasons for these password complexity rules. That is, it is not just the end users who have been misled over the years, but also people who should know better. Because of this, they are unlikely to re-evaluate these decades old rules by looking at what they are (and aren't supposed to do).

I have likened IT manager's adherence to password complexity rules as a "cargo cult". They have come to believe that the rules and customs are vital to security, but have no understanding of how and so misjudge when such rules should be ditched.

Answer (score 3):

> This password is called "weak" by Apple and it won't let me use it 'because of consecutive characters'.

Think of it in terms of probability: if a randomly selected user who proposed a password with many consecutive identical characters was examined, what is more likely, that they're using a password like what you describe, or one like `aaaaaa1!`?

So yeah, it's an annoying rule, but the fact that it prevents somebody like you from using the passwords you describe is, just by itself, not a black mark against it.  The argument you need to make—and one that I believe is likely correct—is that the rule is ineffectual because *most users who run it end up choosing a bad password anyway*.

> It's 20 characters long and hard to guess, what makes it weak?

The way you describe your hypothetical password scheme, nothing in it allows us to reliably **quantify** its strength.  So I'd flip your question around: what makes your passwords strong, and more importantly, **how much**?

Informally, password crackers have two strategies at their disposal:

1. Formulate theories about which passwords are more likely and which are less so, and guess likelier passwords ahead of unlikely ones.

   - Dictionary attacks are the most famous form of this.
2. Test your password guesses at very high speeds.

So to measure the strength of a password, a decent method would be to design a model similar to the attacker's #1, and estimate how many guesses an attacker would make before trying that password.  Some tools try to do this, for example, the [zxcvb password strength meter](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) ([online demo with examples](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html)).

But methods like these have a problem, which is that they rely on the defender not being outsmarted by the attacker.  A better solution is to note that the attacker's two strategies have a very simple counter:

- Choose passwords with **equal likelihood** out of a **sufficiently large set**.

  1. Equal likelihood means that there are no likelier passwords for the attacker to try first.
  2. Large set means that the attacker has to guess a prohibitive number of passwords before they succeed.

And the best password generation strategies are built around this:

1. Password managers use cryptographic random number generators to generate random passwords for you, and store the generated passwords in a database so you don't have to remember them.
2. [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) picks uniform random passphrases using a cheap, auditable random number generator: dice rolls.

So the short version: don't be overconfident about the strength of your homebrew password generation scheme.  Choose one memorable master password with some method that involves dice throwing or similar, and generate the rest of your passwords with a password manager.

Comment: Agree with the general gist of your answer. The challenge I have is that password managers stink on mobile devices and I don't have access to Keepass on machines not my own.